# Why is PDO treating a blank value as null?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, null

I'm trying to insert a record in an automobile table.  Here's a trimmed down version of the table.

**NOTE**: this is not a real life working model, should not be used or evaluated as such. I'm just showing the problem I'm having in a simplified way.

```
mysql> describe desc_autos;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| car_id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| automobile_name | varchar(25)      | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) FROM desc_autos WHERE automobile_name IS NULL;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) FROM desc_autos WHERE automobile_name = '';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    19322 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

+-------------+
CREATE TABLE `desc_autos` (
  `car_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `automobile_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So you see the `automobile_name` field is `NOT NULL`, and blank values are being shown for many records.  *(Disregard field names - just accept there is a field with non-null values)*

I am converting from native MySQL functions to PDO.  If I insert a record with a non-blank `automobile_name` value, no problem - works fine.   If `automobile_name` is blank, PDO balks.

```
    $automobile_name = '';
    try 
    {
        $q = "
            INSERT INTO
                desc_autos
                (
                    automobile_name
                )
            VALUES
                (
                    :automobile_name
                )
        ";
        $stmt = $dbx_pdo->prepare($q);
        $stmt->bindParam(':automobile_name',    $automobile_name,   PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    } catch(PDOException $err) {
        log_error();
        return false;
    }       
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'automobile_name' cannot be null
```

I thought I had to implicitly tell PDO to insert a NULL value, otherwise blank values would be inserted as... blank values.

Ex:

> $stmt->bindValue(':automobile_name', !empty($automobile_name) ?
>   $automobile_name   : NULL, PDO::PARAM_STR);

I'm not needing to insert NULLs in this case - I need to drop a blank, non-null value in the given field.

**The question:**

Why is PDO treating a blank value as null?

Comment: Are you implying the `IS NULL` worked with mysql_query()? Because PDO doesn't really influence MySQL expressions. As for inserting, you're binding the value with `PDO::PARAM_STR`, which will turn NULL values into blank strings.

Comment: @mario My reaction too, but at the top is `$automobile_name = '';` explicitly setting it to the empty string.

Comment: @mario, prior to this the insert query looked like `$q = "INSERT INTO desc_autos (automobile_name) VALUES ( $automobile_name )";` then with `mysqli_query( $dbx, $q);`  If `$automobile_name` was blank (or even null), it would be inserted as a blank value in MySQL.

Comment: Okay. Seems I misread entirely what you want anyway. Go for the non-/implicit conversion flag as advised by @MB, try `->bindValue` (often better retains types), or adapt your table scheme (e.g. `DEFAULT ""` or something).

Comment: @Mario could you add an answer regarding changing table schema?  Setting `automobile_name` to accept NULL values eliminated the error.  I then converted existing blank values to NULL with an `UPDATE`.  This initially appears to resolve the issue in my dev system.    @MichaelBerkowski has a good answer too.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you need to set the `ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS` (nevermind the name) to the appropriate setting so it does not convert empty strings to `NULL`. Apparently your current value is `PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING` causing the empty string `''` to be nulled.

```
// Set it to "natural" mode so NULLs and empty strings aren't modified
$dbx_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_NATURAL);
```

Documentation: [PDO connection attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Note: According to my quick test, `PDO::NULL_NATURAL` would appear to be the default setting, but perhaps yours was modified elsewhere.

Based on your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output, the `automobile_name` column is `NOT NULL` but doesn't explicitly have a default defined. I would probably take the approach of setting the default to the empty string `''` and allowing PDO to insert `NULL`. As mario alluded in the main comment thread:

```
ALTER TABLE desc_autos MODIFY `automobile_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

In the PDOStatement `bindParam()`, you may then use either a PHP `null` or the empty string `''` to force the database to use its default. That would require no changes to your current line:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':automobile_name',    $automobile_name,   PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: While I don't know why it would be named like that, I can confirm that in oracle db, `NULL == ''`. Annoying at times when you are used to other databases.

Comment: Just tried this and continue to get the error - see my comment to the Question for what I was using before.  Looks like I need to modify the table scheme per @mario.

Comment: @acoder Are you using emulated prepares or real ones?  With emulation, I could get NULL to convert to the empty string by modifying this attr, but not the other way around (which is what you want). With real, non-emulated prepares I can't either to make a difference. But looking at your table, it looks like you already have `''` as the default value.  Can you post `SHOW CREATE TABLE desc_autos`?

Comment: NOte that this is potentially solved now - I changed `automobile_name` to accept null values in my dev system and this eliminated the error.

Comment: @acoder Well if you don't want nulls, still you should go ahead with changing it to `DEFAULT ''`

Comment: For this table nulls are OK. This could make a difference though, if I were querying looking for blank values instead of nulls.  Not the case here.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Any idea for what reasons this does not work for me?:( P.S. i m not using it in `setAttribute` but in connection options